# Access .properties file at same level as working directory

Tags: java, properties, jar

I am working on a Java project that I want to deliver to my client as a .jar file.  However, I want to allow the client to be able to change the parameters of the program without having to recompile or recreate the .jar.  Basically, I want to be able to load .properties files from classes inside the .jar but locate those .properties files outside of the .jar and even outside the working directory.

I have been testing my attempts inside Eclipse, which might be causing some of the problem but I don't see how at the moment.  My setup is a follows.   I have one project that contains a few classes that I build a .jar file from.  I have a .properties file that is used to create a ResourceBundle whenever a class for the .jar is created.  I specify that an additional directory, "conf/", be included in the .jar classpath within the .jar manifest.

Once the .jar file is built, it is copied to the lib/ directory of another project which I am using for testing.  This test project includes the .jar file as a library ("Add External Jars..") in the Java Build Path.  The .properties file is located the conf/ directory which is at the same level as lib/, src/, and bin/ but I am unable to accces it there.  The only way I have been able to get it to work is to locate conf/ under src/ (and bin/) but I would like to be able to use it up one level.  Is this possible?

Here's the entry in the .jar manifest file...

```
Class-Path: ../conf/
```

Here's the ResourceBundle call that I tried (didn't work)...

```
rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("..conf.BaseProject");
```

Here's the directory structure that works now (names have been changed to protect the innocent)...

```
/Project
/Project/bin
/Project/bin/conf
/Project/bin/conf/BaseProject.properties
/Project/bin/TestClass.class
/Project/lib
/Project/lib/BaseProject.jar
```

Here's the directory layout I want (again, file names not important)...

```
/Project
/Project/bin
/Project/bin/TestClass.class
/Project/conf
/Project/conf/BaseProject.properties
/Project/lib
/Project/lib/BaseProject.jar
```

Comment: Did you try simply `getBundle("BaseProject")`?

Comment: Yes, I did try just using "BaseProject" and that way does work when conf/ is in the bin/ directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it [using the Classloader](http://www.javaworld.com/javaforums/showflat.php?Number=551).

Answer (score 1):

I like Spring's [ClassPathResource](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html)